# Xcode is crashing while doing "Convert to ObjectiveC ARC"

Tags: xcode, crash

There is a strange crash issue happening with Xcode whenever I am trying to do automatic conversion to ARC.

When I do the following

Refactor--> "Convert to ObjectiveC ARC",  I am getting the following error crash.I tried it with Xcode 6.1.1, Xcode 6.0.1, Xcode 6.2

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6528/DVTKit/ViewControllers/DVTViewController.m:152
Details:  view should be an instance inheriting from DVTControllerContentView, but it is <NSView: 0x7ff3afda9d10>
```